# Assigning a char-array to a string-array pointer results in a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

I'm using a pointer array that holds strings.

```
int numwords = 0;
int capacity = 0;
string* words = new string[capacity];
char line[10];

...

resize(){
    capacity = capacity*2 +1;
    string* temp = new string[capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < numwords; i++){
            temp[i] = words[i];
    }
    delete [] words;
    words = temp;
}

...

words[numwords] = string(line);
numwords++;
```

and whenever it reaches this part, it segfaults. *numwords* remains 0 throughout. Numwords is only incremented at the end of a while loop.

No errors come up at all until runtime, so i'm pretty sure I'm making the pointer array correctly.

I did find an answer to a similar question elsewhere.

```
string strVal[3] = {"Good","Better","Best"};
string* strPtr = strVal;
```

But I still have no idea what I may or may not be doing right.

Comment: What are numwords and capacity when you get the segfault? Have resize been called?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using a `std::vector`?

Comment: @warsac numwords remains 0 throughout, and capacity goes to 1.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's part of the requirements to use a string pointer array

Comment: is line[10] null terminated ?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The initial code `int capacity = 0; string* words = new string[capacity];` creates a pointer to an "array" with zero elements. Doing *anything* with `words` is now like juggling razorblades! `words[any index]` is an out-of-range access...

Comment: @BoPersson should capacity be 1?

Comment: I don't know, I just say that it is unusual and dangerous to have zero size arrays. I usually have a `std::vector<std::string>` and avoid these problems.

Comment: Is the string class you use an std::string or something you have written? Is line ever assigned something before it is used?

Comment: Eventually, you'll discover `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>`, and all your crashes will go away.